# Uncertainty in a logic engine (Produce plausible relative positions based on local geography)

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, logic-programming

I know there's a high chance of my hitting the XY problem here, so the first chunk of this is about the more general situation.

---

### The Problem

I have a set of data points containing abstract geographic-feature information, but no actual locations (absolute or relative). For the sake of example, let's call it the following list of cities that describes the local terrain, but with no coordinates or relative positioning:

- City A is on an island and on a hill.
- City B is on the coast and near a river.
- City C is on a mountain and near a river
- City D is on an island and on a hill.
- City E is on an island and on plains.

From this, I want to write a program that can provide relative positions for these locations. For the above list, it might derive that A and D are near each other, E might be near them but is less likely, and B and C might be near each other. You can think of it as a graph with all the edges rubbed out, and the program tries to write them back in based on the properties of the nodes. Given that, it could then come up with some arbitrary coordinates for each city, from which a map might be drawn.

I don't need a unique solution – my end-goal here is plausible maps of unmapped-but-described fictional places.

This seems to me to be the sort of problem that's a good fit for e.g. Prolog or similar logic-engines, since it's basically just constraint resolution. However, I can't quite work it out myself. The issues I'm hitting at the moment relate to the way that, for example, two cities could have similar local features without being near the same instance of that larger feature. It's the difference between "This city is near some unspecified mountain" and "This city is near Mt. Foobar." The latter provides a strong constraint (two cities both near Mt. Foobar are near each other), but the latter only provides a guideline (two cities both near mountains are more likely to be near each other than one city near a mountain and another city not near a mountain).

---

### The Question

How does one define (and provide solutions based on) probabilities, rather than absolutes, in Prolog or other logic/rules engines?

Comment: Interesting, but probably a bit too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using MiniZinc (a very nice constraint modeling language).

The assumptions of the model is that there is a map of fixed places, e.g. where the mountains, hills, rivers, etc are. (I'm not sure if that is in your assumptions. For a different model, see below.)

The objective is then to place a number of cities (in this model cities A..H) using these constraints
   - near(P1,P2): P1 and P2 must be within a distance (defined by "near_distance")
   - on(P1,P2): the city P1 must be on or very near a fixed place
   - not_near(P1,P2): the places P1 and P2 must not be near

I changed one of the original constraint and added some more cities and constraints.

This model is also here: http://hakank.org/minizinc/place_cities2.mzn .
The solution is after the model

```
include "globals.mzn"; 

% The places
enum places       = {island,hill,coast,river,mountain,plains,
                   city_a,city_b,city_c,city_d,city_e,city_f,city_g,city_h
                 };

int: empty  = 0;

set of int: fixed_places = {island,hill,coast,river,mountain,plains};
set of int: to_place = places diff fixed_places; % {city_a,city_b,city_c,city_d,city_e,city_f,city_g,city_h};

int: num_places = length(places);
int: max_x;
int: max_y;
int: near_distance;

array[1..max_x, 1..max_y] of int: data;
array[0..num_places] of string: places_s = array1d(0..num_places, 
                            ["-","i","h","c","r","m","p",
                             "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H",
                             ]);


 % decision variables
 % position of a city
 array[to_place] of var 1..max_x: x;
 array[to_place] of var 1..max_y: y;

 % the grid (0 is an empty spot)
 array[1..max_x, 1..max_y] of var 0..num_places: grid;


 % on: must be really near.
 % Assumption: p2 is a fixed_place
 predicate on(var 1..num_places: p1, var 1..num_places: p2) =
    exists(I in 1..max_x, J in 1..max_y) (
     data[I,J] = p2 /\
     pow(abs(x[p1]-I),2) + pow(abs(y[p1]-J),2) <= 1
  )
;

% define the concept of near: atmost d distance apart
predicate near(var 1..num_places: p1, var 1..num_places: p2) =
   exists(I in 1..max_x, J in 1..max_y) (
     grid[I,J] = p2 /\
     pow(abs(x[p1]-I),2) + pow(abs(y[p1]-J),2) <= near_distance
  )
;

% not near: > d distance apart
predicate not_near(var int: p1, var int: p2) =
  exists(I in 1..max_x, J in 1..max_y) (
     grid[I,J] = p2 /\
     pow(abs(x[p1]-I),2) + pow(abs(y[p1]-J),2) > near_distance
  )
;



solve satisfy;
% solve :: int_search(x ++ y ++ array1d(grid), input_order, indomain_split, complete) satisfy;

% general constraints
constraint
 % Here we ensure that:
 %   - a fixed place can only be positioned by the fixed place or a city
 %   - if an empty spot (in data[I,J]) then it can only be positioned by a city
 forall(I in 1..max_x, J in 1..max_y) (
    if data[I,J] != empty then 
        (grid[I,J] in {data[I,J]} union to_place)
        /\ grid[I,J] != empty
    else 
     grid[I,J] in to_place union {empty}
    endif
 ) 
;

% city constraints
constraint
 % City A is on an island and on a hill.
  on(city_a,island)  /\
  on(city_a, hill) /\

 % City B is on the coast and near a river.
   on(city_b,coast) /\
   near(city_b,river) /\

 % City C is on a mountain and near a river
   on(city_c,mountain) /\
   near(city_c,river) /\

 % City D is on an island and on a hill.
  on(city_d,island) /\
  on(city_d,hill) /\

%%%City E is on an island and on plains.
%   % on(city_e,island) /\
% Changed it to:
% City E is near the mountains and on plains
near(city_e, mountain) /\
on(city_e,plains) 


% ADDED: 
%  City F is on mountains and near a river
/\
 on(city_f, mountain) /\
 near(city_f,river) 

/\
near(city_g, mountain) /\
near(city_g, hill) 

/\
on(city_h,plains) /\ 
% near(city_h,hill) % /\
% not_near(city_h,city_c) /\
not_near(city_h,city_f)

;

constraint
  % connect the x[p] and y[p] arrays with grid[I,J]
  forall(p in to_place) ( 
     exists(I in 1..max_x, J in 1..max_y) (
       x[p] = I /\ y[p] = J  /\ grid[I,J] = p
     ) 
   )

   % unique place in grid  
   % all cities have unique positions
   /\ all_different([(x[p]*num_places-1)+ y[p]  | p in to_place])

   /\ % each city has just one place in the grid
   forall(p in to_place) (
      sum([grid[I,J] = p | I in 1..max_x, J  in 1..max_y]) <= 1
   )
 ;

 output [
    "x: \(x)\ny: \(y)\n"
 ]
 ++ 
 [
   join("", [places_s[fix(grid[I,J])] | J in 1..max_y]) ++ "\n"
   | I in 1..max_x % , J in 1..max_y
 ]
 ;


 %
 % data
 %  
 max_x = 15;
 max_y = 15;
 near_distance = 4;
 data = array2d(1..max_x,1..max_y,
 [
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,river,empty,empty,coast,empty,island,hill,hill,empty,
   empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,river,empty,empty,coast,empty,empty,island,island,empty,
   empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,river,empty,empty,empty,coast,coast,coast,coast,coast,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,river,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
     empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,river,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
   empty,empty,mountain,mountain,mountain,mountain,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,mountain,mountain,mountain,mountain,mountain,empty,empty,empty,hill,hill,hill,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,hill,hill,hill,empty,empty,
   empty,empty,empty,empty,plains,plains,plains,plains,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,plains,plains,plains,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,mountain,mountain,mountain,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
  empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,mountain,mountain,mountain,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
   empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
   empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,
 ]);
```

The data is based on this (fictional) map with the abbreviations.

```
i: island
h: hill
c: coast
r: river
m: mountain
p: plains

......r..c.ihh.
......r..c..ii.
......r...ccccc
......r........
......r........
..mmmm.........
..mmmmm...hhh..
..........hhh..
....pppp.......
....ppp........
...............
......mmm......
```

Here is one solution where the capital letters are the cities to be placed:

```
x: [1, 1, 5, 1, 9, 5, 7, 10]
y: [13, 9, 6, 12, 4, 5, 9, 4]
------r-Bc-DAh-
------r--c--ii-
------r---ccccc
------r--------
----FCr--------
--mmmm---------
--mmmmm-G-hhh--
----------hhh--
---Epppp-------
---Hppp--------
---------------
------mmm------
------mmm------
---------------
---------------
```

It is solved in some second with the Gecode FlatZinc solver (most of the time is converting to the general FlatZinc format).

One advantage of a Constraint Programming solver is that it's very easy to generate many solutions , e.g. compared to most MIP solvers and most/many SAT solvers.

Two further comments:
- I first interpreted the question that there is now known position at all. The model is here: http://hakank.org/minizinc/place_cities.mzn
  Note that it assumes that there is only one mountain, one river, etc.

- Also, I realized after building these models that the problem reminds of the "classic" Nadel's Construction problem cited in Rina Dechter "Constraint Processing", page 5. The objective is then to place certain things near or not near some places.  I have implemented that problem in some CP systems:

  - MiniZinc: http://hakank.org/minizinc/nadel.mzn
  - Picat: http://hakank.org/picat/nadel.pi
  - B-Prolog: http://hakank.org/bprolog/nadel.pl
  - ECLiPSe CLP: http://hakank.org/eclipse/nadel.ecl
  - SICStus Prolog:  http://hakank.org/sicstus/nadel.pl
  - Gecode: http://hakank.org/gecode/nadel.cpp

Comment: I should probably mention that this is not a probabilistic model at all, but a very "crisp" model.

Comment: s/Dichter/Dechter/g

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_(EDA)) problem to me, so you should try investigating approaches to solve it.

I'll use [satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) framework to discuss uncertainty and related stuff. You can define **a 2D grid**, each node can hold *features* - a hill, a river, a mountain. Features could be generic or special (Mt. Foobar). Some features could be predefined - you can place a mountain at specified node, but it's up to you. Cities are defined as features too.

Now, interesting part. You can define a set of constraints **over** such grid. So, for each node in a grid you can define something like this:

> IF city A takes place at node THEN a mountain must be at an adjacent node
>
> IF given node contains a mountain THEN city A must be at any of adjacent nodes
>
> IF city A is present at given node THEN city B can't be at any of adjacent nodes

You can introduce a lot of various constraints in such way, even with counting objects:

> IF a node has a river THEN no more than 2 cities could be at adjacent nodes

To do so, you can rely on [pseudo-boolean constraints](http://minisat.se/downloads/MiniSat+.pdf). You can use it even for optimizing solutions by introducing counters for specific configurations and require that here must be *more than* or *less than* of them.

To solve resulting problem you can use any of SAT solvers (e.g. [Glucose](http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/))

You can generate several *different* solutions by using [AllSAT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00523), there are solvers for that too.

If purely Boolean formulation is too complex, you can try [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories)

Details how to implement such systems are out the question's scope, it's too broad and require plenty of preliminary studies.

Hope that my answer is helpful.

EDIT

SAT solver returns *first* correct solution and it'll be random in this sense.

Comment: Hm. On the one hand, this looks like it has potential. On the other hand, I haven't touched SAT since I was first learning what NP meant years ago, I've never so much as looked at circuit design, and I haven't the faintest idea how to map SAT to a grid except possibly by having a different boolean for each possible coordinate for each feature.

Comment: @DavidHeyman I'll add details on that into my answer during this day, maybe this weekend. Actually, it's not THAT difficult.

Comment: @DavidHeyman Yes, you'll have to introduce Boolean variables to each feature at each node. Is it crucial? It depends on a problem size and memory/runtime limits. SAT approach is very flexible and pretty efficient. I worked on a project in circuit design that solves problems with 10^4 variables and 10^6 constraints. It takes hours, but still it works. :) Plus, it allows you introducing any kind of constraints without hardcoding them into solving algorithm.

Comment: Mostly a sinking feeling of "I'm going to have to write my own tooling for this, aren't I," where with Prolog I can write one rule and it automatically applies to all coordinates and such. But to within my slim knowledge of SAT problems, I'd need to do a lot to automate producing all the variables and conditions just to say "a specific feature is in one location and no two features are in the same location", and the result would be massive and as legible as bytecode.

Comment: @DavidHeyman  you can using the same approach with Prolog, it should be very similar. You can try to look at [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories). It gives you the same capabilities, but should be simpler to use. It could be even simpler than Prolog, but it depends on tastes.